# Regarding calculation of date difference in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I have a table which consist of column like movies ,date etc and i have to find difference of date in movies watch please specify the query thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has native support for date arithmetic. You can subtract one date from another - e.g. `SELECT SYSDATE - date_watched FROM movies_table` will return a the number of days between today's date and `date_watched`.

You need to provide more detail about your requirements for a more exact answer - e.g. table structure, sample data, expected output.